# Why do I need an FQDN for a Hypervisor used only for running in house VMs for software testing?

Tags: security, hypervisor, fqdn

I'm testing ProxMox, and during installation it asks for an FQDN.

I've entered test.local, and it accepted it but I suppose I would have to enter something like cluster1.companyname.com, and then ensure that DNS will point that subdomain to the IP of the office, and the router will have to port forward to the specific machine the hypervisor is running on.

But what is the point of this, except for of course that I could access the hypervisor from anywhere in the world?

Isn't this a security risk?

Answer (score 6):

The FQDN is used internally by ProxMox for:

- generating self referral URLs
- generating SSL certificates
- domain to use for sending emails
- Linux hostname of the ProxMox machine
- displaying the name of the ProxMox machine

Answer (score 0):

The FQDN here just means that you enter a distinguished name with includes hostname + domainname. It does not have to be necessarily a DNS record in the root DNS servers, but could also be a registered name in your company's DNS.

By the way, just because one can lookup your FQND and resolve it to an IP address does not imply security risks. Just hiding the name when a server is connected directly to the internet has nothing to do with security.